# How can I restore LaTeX standard font for math equations in a sty file?

Tags: math-mode, classicthesis

I am using the style file for classic thesis, which can be downloaded [in this link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) and can be viewed [in this link](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty). I like everything about this style file except the font used for math equations. How can I modify the `classicthesis.sty` such that math equations are printed the same as the standard LaTeX math?

Comment: Can you show how you call `classicthesis`? The options you pass to the package are needed.

Comment: @egreg: the developer has an example for using the this package, which can be downloaded at https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/downloads/detail?name=classicthesis.v4.1.zip&can=2&q=.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I get from this simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
This is inline math $a+b=c$ and a displayed formula follows:
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The font used for math is MathPaZo, which is tailored to accompany the default Palatino text font.

If I change the example in the following way

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,eulermath]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
This is inline math $a+b=c$ and a displayed formula follows:
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\end{document}
```

(note the `eulermath` option), I get Euler Math for the formulas.

[image]

If instead you load `lmodern` after `classicthesis`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
This is inline math $a+b=c$ and a displayed formula follows:
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\end{document}
```

you get the "standard" LaTeX fonts

[image]

Comment: I edited in `eulermath`, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ScottH. Thanks! I wanted to put it in, and I forgot.

Comment: @egreg, I want to use your solution but the problem is after using `lmodern` the font of text is also changed and I'm happy with the text font. How can I used your solution while maintaining the normal text font?

Comment: @Pouya I don't understand what you're asking: using Computer (or Latin) Modern math with Palatino is a no-go, they are visually incompatible.